# Get rest of the path from requested route in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Can you get the rest of the path in node.js from reuqested route using **express**?

Assuming I have my server on port `8080` and I just visit http://example.com:8080/get/path/to/file

```
var url = require("url");
app.get("/get/*", function(req, res) {
  console.log(req.path);

  // this will return
  // '/get/path/to/file'

  console.log(url.parse(req.path);

  // this will return
  // protocol: null,
  // slashes: null,
  // auth: null,
  // host: null,
  // port: null,
  // hostname: null,
  // hash: null,
  // search: null,
  // query: null,
  // pathname: '/get/path/to/file',
  // path: '/get/path/to/file',
  // href: '/get/path/to/file' }
});
```

What I want here is to return `path/to/file` is there a way to get that? or could it be my `app.get()` route is wrong here?

I know that there are ways to do it using `regex`, `split`, `substring` and many other ways using plain JavaScript, but just want to see the best way to go for this.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure how this works, did you mean `app.get("/get/*", function(req, res) {` ?

Comment: So `req.path` contains the path you want right, what is it you're really asking for? Are you sure you're not just looking for variable URL's, as in `app.get("/get/:path/:file", ...` and then catch them in `req.params.path` etc

Comment: @adeneo I want to be able to get anything after `/get` so if I visit `http://example.com/get/this/is/what/i/want` I should get back `this/is/what/i/want`

Comment: Then I'd say you should just do `req.path.replace('/get','')`, as that would be the easiest solution. There are probably ways to catch the asterisk in the route in params, just not quite sure how as I've never needed that.

Comment: @adeneo I think your solution by far make the most sense and easy fix. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can find `path/to/file` in [`req.params`](http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#req.params):

> When a regular expression is used for the route definition, capture groups are provided in the array using req.params[N], where N is the nth capture group. This rule is applied to unnamed wild-card matches with string routes such as `/file/*`:

```
// GET /get/path/to/file
req.params[0]
// => path/to/file
```

Comment: The problem with `params` is that I have to change my routing in `app.get()` to be something else to work not the way I have it currently which I'm fine with changing except I'm trying to figure out why it doesn't work.

Comment: @Ali what do you mean "Doesn't seem to work", is `req.params` empty?

Comment: I'm getting this `Cannot GET /get/path/to/file`

Comment: That's very odd - you're not even reaching the point where you can access `req.params`.  The problem is elsewhere.  Check your server logs.

Comment: You are right! It was a mistake from my server part because there was a route after that trying to override req.params[0] everytime.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a really old question, but I will post the answer for anyone searching for this.
At the time of writing I am using express 4.18.2.
To match the remainder of a route you can actually do something like this:

```js
app.get("/some/url/:pathToFile(*)", (req, res) => {
  const pathToFile = req.params["pathToFile"]; //<- Holds the remainder of the route.
});
```

So navigating to /some/url/path/to/file will result in the route above being matched and the pathToFile variable will be "path/to/file".